# style.width.% incorrect on last cell when using clr-datagrid with clrDgRowSelection if browser is not full screen

Tags: angular, datagrid, vmware-clarity

This is a frustrating one; quite frankly I'm a bit dumbfounded by it

Any thoughts, guidance, suggestions, etc. would be greatly appreciated ... aside from using a completely different datagrid (e.g. NgPrime), I'm not really sure how to move forward with this problem.

I've updated packages today to ensure running the latest release

```
Angular CLI: 6.2.4
Node: 8.12.0
Clarity: 0.13.3
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-light-theme-v013-1narkk

What I am experiencing locally and when deploying is not exactly the same issue that is seen in the StackBlitz, which is frustrating ...

The StackBlitz shows a problem wherein the last cell's width extends into the previous cell of the same row ... which is also problematic, but it's not exactly the problem that I'm dealing with ...

The only difference left between my env and the StackBlitz is the use of `<router-outlet>` in the `<div class="content-area">` element - not sure whether that would matter ...

FULL SCREEN (last row's width allows the text to stretch out)
[image: full screen - rowSelection true]

NOT FULL SCREEN (last row's width prematurely wraps the text)
NOTE - the cursor changes from 'pointer' back to 'hand' just after the text wraps - so it seems that the row's label element width is incorrect ...
[image: not full screen - rowSelection true]

It appears that the `label class="datagrid-row-clickable"` is proportionally limited to the available screen width that is not taken up by the browser (this is just a theory)
[image: not full screen - rowSelection true - showing remaining desktop space]

Note - this symptom does NOT occur if `[clrDgRowSelection]="true"` is NOT used on the `clr-datagrid` - as shown below ...
[image: not full screen - no rowSelection used]

Could be related to

https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues/2692

NOTE - removing the `[style.width.%]="c.width"` reproduces the issues shown in this StackBlitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-datagrid-issue-2525-reproduction

Comment: Hey @Bret - I'm having a hard time understanding what your issue is and how to reproduce it. It seems like you want to set a width on all of the columns and the width of the last column isn't what you expect. I think this is because of the flex nature of the columns and cells. If all columns have a fixed width the layout for the datagrid needs the last column/cell to flex so that it takes up the remaining space in the datagrid. This also has implications for the overflow property. Can edit your question to ask a specific question related to the code in the first stackblitz?

Comment: I'm using `[style.width.%]` - so it's supposed to be percentage-based not an absolute number of pixels ... if I don't set the columns width, then the first column is really, really big and the rest of the column end up very small - as mentioned in the last sentence "issue-2525-reproduction"

Comment: @hippeelee - also ... the problem that can be seen (shown with the screenshots only unfortunately) doesn't appear to be reproducible on the StackBlitz ... why can't the row width be calculated the same way when you use the clrDgRowSelection and when you don't use it -- because when I don't use it, there isn't a problem ...

Comment: Oh, I see now. Sorry I just assumed pixels. Without an explicit width set the column/cell will use flex. I wouldn't advise using percentages. Is there a reason you aren't using the autosizing that ships with the datagrid?

Comment: There is a rendering bug related to the `clrDgRowSelection` element that causes an error when calculating row width. I have a PR fix for that and it should be ready soon.

Comment: As mentioned, if I don't set the widths - the first column is extremely wide and the remaining columns are very short - honestly, I'd prefer that Clarity handled automatically setting the column widths based on the row data.

Comment: I'm not seeing that behavior in your stackblitz so its hard to say whats going on. there is a min width column size of 4rem (96px) on columns. If you can post a working example that replicates the issue I'll be happy to take a look and try to help. Without that I'm afraid that I can only guess as to whats happening with your use case.

Comment: Take a look at this simple demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-light-theme-v013-obhh3h If you change the width of the viewport you will see how the column size changes based on the content. This is the sizing behavior provided by the datagrid. On top of that a column width can be set that will be taken into account when the content is rendered. If you can modify the demo i linked to at the start of this comment so that it has the same issue you are having it would assist me in helping you.

Comment: modified your demo to add the clrDgRowSelection - column sizing is broken (as seen in the "issue-2525-production" - perhaps the PR fix mentioned will fix that?  If so, I'll simply wait for the release that includes the fix - then remove styling the columns widths from my code

Comment: Can you post a link to the modified stackblitz?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-light-theme-v013-pd3my6

Comment: Did you turn it off and turn it back on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally determined the issue ...

When using the [ngx-contextmenu](https://github.com/isaacplmann/ngx-contextmenu) - there is a required stylesheet link for bootstrap (seen in [its StackBlitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-contextmenu-example?file=src%2Findex.html))

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Removing that link tag fixes the behavior I found when the browser was not maximized

The context menu is no longer styled properly ... but that is not related to VMware's Clarity framework